# How can I show the inline parameter list with a keybinding while typing a function?

Tags: keyboard, user-interface

Is there a way to invoke either of these contextual menu buttons that popup when typing?

[image: screenshot]

I don't really like to move my hand over to the mouse just to see in what order the parameters are supposed to be, and hitting F1 to open the docs is a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to press the down arrow key once, and then <kbd>enter</kbd> on the top choice if you want to go to the help menu. If you want to trigger the function template you can go one down and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Experiment in making a screen recording with keyboard:

[image]